# ps command doesn't work in docker container

Tags: debian, docker

I want to do a ps command in a docker container derived from Debian official Docker hub repository:

```
$ docker run -ti debian:wheezy /bin/bash
root@51afd6b09af8:/# ps
bash: ps: command not found
```

Answer (score 984, accepted):

`ps` is not installed in the base `wheezy` image. Try this from within the container:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install procps
```

*or* add the following line to the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: If you get this error "The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install procps' returned a non-zero code: 1" then use `apt-get install -y procps` instead.

Comment: Here is the URL that discussed in 2014 of not including `ps` in wheezy image: `https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/447#issuecomment-36647268`

Comment: RUN     apt-get update &&
    apt-get install -y procps && 
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Comment: Where should it be added?
I think in .yml file when creating your docker image?

Comment: Remove RUN from your command, I think it is a typo.

Comment: Note that `ps` on the docker host might work fine for you.

Comment: @tjurkan I suspect it is not a typo. The line is meant to be added to the Dockerfile that is used to build the container image for the container in question.

Comment: Yes, now it is clear, if you use it in the Dockerfile then you need RUN in front of the command, but in case you log to the container with something like: docker exec -it <contnum> bash, and then execute it, then you don't need the RUN command in front of it.

Comment: After further checking, the command mentioned in the question would download debian:wheezy image from remote repo if it is not present locally and login to the container based on that image as root. From there, RUN command is not necessary in front of other commands.

Comment: The edit is wrong, and I'm going to revert it back: OP is clearly asking _how do I run a ps command in a docker container_ *not* _how do I add ps to the original Dockerfile_, and get it forever into the image.

Comment: My edit has been rejected, apparently. I don't know why, but running `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps` within a running container will not lead to nothing else than an error. The original post, which was also the accepted answer, was fine as it was.

Comment: Yo, get rid of  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
Its unnecessary and could have unwanted effects on the package manager

Comment: It has the *wanted* effect of removing the data that was added by `apt-get update` earlier in the command, to reduce the size of the resulting image.  If you're going to add more packages later, you have to run `apt-get update` again anyway. You can't rely on it being done by an earlier layer, since that layer might be in the build cache and have outdated information

Comment: This answer helped for LXC container as well.

Answer (score 157):

use docker top

```
docker top <container ID>
```

Comment: Great answer! Eliminates the need to install `procps` on the container. Thanks.

Comment: The reason why one would ask for `ps` is to check if something is running inside the container or not. So the guy usually would go `docker run smth /bin/bah` and then `ps`. If nothing is running docker exits. With smth like `--rm` the evidence of process gone and this command does not work for obvious reasons for stopped containers. It can be a workaround if smth's working otherwise not an option for investigation.

Comment: NOTE: `docker top <container ID>`shows the PID of the reflected process in the host computer, not the PID of the internal processes inside the container, as you can see executing `cd /proc/; ls -ld [1-9]*`

Answer (score 106):

In case you can't install the procps package (don't have proper permissions) you can use /proc directory.

The first few directories (named as numbers) are PIDs of your processes. Inside directories, you can find additional information useful to decipher which process is connected to each PID. For example, you can use the cat command to view "cmdline" file to check which process is connected to PID.

```
$ ls /proc
1 10 11 ...

$ ls -1 /proc/22
attr
autogroup
auxv
cgroup
clear_refs
cmdline
...

$ cat /proc/22/cmdline 
/bin/sh
```

Edited - spaces are lost in the cmdline so we can pipe the cat output to the `tr` command, for example:

```
$ cat /proc/1/cmdline | tr '\0' ' '
/sbin/init splash
```

Comment: While not as convenient, this seems the more appropriate answer.

Comment: To see the spaces I had to run "cat /proc/22/cmdline | xargs -0"

Answer (score 24):

If you're running a CentOS container, you can install ps using this command:

```
yum install -y procps
```

Running this command on Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum install -y procps
```

Answer (score 19):

Firstly, run the command below:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install procps
```

and then run:

```
ps -ef
```

Answer (score 7):

Kali users fix for bash: ps: command not found issue is:

```bash
apt install procps
```

Answer (score 1):

For RockyLinux 9, you need to use this command

```
$> yum install procps-ng
```

Comment: Works for CentOS 9 as well.