# list process inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have docker image starting from python:3.10-slim.
As the container running (name container_a), I would like to check the process running inside the container.

1. docker top container_a: I am able to see three threads.
2. docker exec container_a ps: executable not found in $PATH
3. docker exec -it container_a sh: I am able to enter inside the container, and again I could not find ps or top under /bin

Anyone knows other command to list the process?

Thank you very much!

I have tried search command to list processes in Linux. It seems that both ps and top are common ones but neither works in the Slim linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ps command doesn't work in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982274/ps-command-doesnt-work-in-docker-container)

Comment: The point of `slim` is that it only includes a very "slim" set of utilities, and apparently that does not include `ps`.  You'll have to install it like in the linked duplicate, or use `docker top`.

Comment: There's probably only one process, whatever your Dockerfile specified as its `CMD`.  What is your goal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As highlighted by other comments, `-slim` tags are meant to, well, be *slim*. That images contain just what the main application needs to work, not what you need for interactive use. If you really want to, try:

```
docker run -it python:3.10-slim sh     
apt update && apt install procps
ps
```

This adds a few megabytes to the original image. To retain changes, use  `docker tag` or `docker commit`, or a custom Dockerfile that `RUN`s previous apt commands